# Is it feasible to write a DApp that targets multiple blockchains

Tags: blockchain, dapps, nethereum, immutable

This question does not target Ethereum specifically, but I hope you can help me out! If my questions are too specific, I apologize in advance.

I'm trying to utilize Blockchain's immutable + provable nature of transactions. As I currently have only one node, I assume I can only utilize a public Blockchain and hook up a DApp to it.

I know of various frameworks for Ethereum DApps (like Nethereum), though I don't want to be restricted solely to the Ethereum Blockchain. This includes various other Blockchain-specific frameworks.

**Are there any frameworks which allow for changing the framework to a different Blockchain, without too much trouble?**

**Also if this does not exist, would such an approach be feasible for one person without a framework?**

I did quite a broad research, but sadly did not find any answers. Only assumption I have is that it's not possible due to only Ethereum being Turing-complete, thus limiting smart-contracts for other blockchains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are there any frameworks which allow for changing the framework to a different Blockchain, without too much trouble?

No and yes. Currently applications are specific to a particular blockchain virtual machine. For example, Ethereum Virtual Machine runs on Ethereum mainnet, but also on Rootstock RSK and Avalanche chains.

Currently other viable chains that do not have EVM support include EOS, Near and Zilliqa.

> Also if this does not exist, would such an approach be feasible for one person without a framework?

No.

Comment: Do you know any reason why there is no multi-chain application yet? It seems weird to me that the only project I heard of is "Polkadot" and this is arriving at the end of this year supposedly.

Thanks for the clarity so far!

Comment: Because there is no demand for such applications, inter blockchain communication is many orders of magnitudes harder problem and most of chains outside Ethereum have zero traction.

Comment: Okay, I guess there just isn't much faith in future blockchains gaining traction at the moment. I'll remain hopeful for the future. Thanks for the answers!